# Python numpy How to sort a ndarray based on a row

Tags: python, numpy, sorting, multidimensional-array, row

how do I sort a ndarray based on one of its rows?
example:

```py
ndarray = [['a' 'b' 'c']
           ['2' '7' '6']
           ['3' '0' '1']]
```

I sort based on the second row and i have:

```py
newsortedndarray = [['a' 'c' 'b']
                    ['2' '6' '7']
                    ['3' '1' '0']]
```

please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [argsort function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) to get an order of "columns".

```
ndarray[:,np.argsort(ndarray[1,:])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can `np.transpose()` your array to make the former columns your new rows.

Comment: but wouldnt that just give me:
```python
[['a' '2' '3']
['b' '7' '0']
['c' '6' '1']]
```